# Need help with cuepoints (Adobe Director project)!

Tags: lingo

I have a little problem, there is a cd project done by another developer in Adobe Director. It is in three languages. This project has video files with subtitles... Subtitles attached to video with the help of cue points... if user selects another language, subtitles change as well... the library has images with text(i.e. subtitles), those images have names like cue points plus at the end there is a sort of language code. For example firstSentRu, or firstSentEn, and corresponding cue point has name firstSen. So I hope the logic is clear...  The problem with those cue points is that when the user navigates between the languages, the last subtitle appears in previous language, and as soon as the video reaches next cue point, subtitles change to current language. I understand why this happens, but because I am a bit new in this I donno how to solve this little problem. Alternative to this could be starting a video from the beginning when the user changes the language... again I donno how...

I hope you can suggest me a way out,
thanks in advance:)!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the place where the language change is done and send an event to update the subtitle to the object that controls it. This system probably relies on a global flag to identify the language (bad !)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you will need to create a proper data structure from the cuepoints in the library - although I would imagine that the code you inherited already does this. The obvious choice would be a list. Once you have this, you should be able to use findPosNear() to get the previous cuepoint. It will require using a sorted list, though.